# Foreign key points to non existent record

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assume the following tables and trigger exist.

```
CREATE TABLE "parent_table"
(
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE "child_table"
(
    id        bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id uuid,
    CONSTRAINT "child_table_parent_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("parent_id") REFERENCES "parent_table" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_child_trigger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER "on_change_add_change_event"
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON "child_table"
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE "add_child_trigger"();
```

Execute the following statements:

```
INSERT INTO "parent_table" VALUES ('a275b51e-9a4f-460f-a0df-589fac39f9fe');
INSERT INTO "child_table" ("parent_id") VALUES ('a275b51e-9a4f-460f-a0df-589fac39f9fe');
DELETE FROM "parent_table" WHERE "id" = 'a275b51e-9a4f-460f-a0df-589fac39f9fe';
```

Then notice that obviously one entry in `child_table` still exists, but that it points to a non-existent `parent_table` record. I thought foreign key guaranteed, that a target record exists, didn't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is surprising behavior, but according to [this message](https://postgr.es/m/2014740.1696254593%40sss.pgh.pa.us) working as expected:

> > CREATE FUNCTION silly() RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 'BEGIN RETURN NULL; END;';
> > CREATE TRIGGER silly BEFORE DELETE ON child FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION silly();
> >
> > The trigger function cancels the cascaded delete on "child", and we are left with
> > a row in "child" that references no row in "parent".
>
> Yes.  This is by design: triggers operate at a lower level than
> foreign keys, so an ill-conceived trigger can break an FK constraint.
> That's documented somewhere, though maybe not visibly enough.
>
> There are good reasons to want triggers to be able to see and
> react to FK-driven updates, so it's unlikely that we'd want to
> revisit that design decision, even if it hadn't already stood
> for decades.
>
> regards, tom lane